# Passing data using navigation component - How come I need a values for the constructor when the guide doesn't?

Tags: java, android, navigation

I am using [this android guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args) for passing data between navigation destinations.

You can see in the code snippet below the guide doesn't need any values passed to the constructor, and it sets the values rather than passing them:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   EditText amountTv = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount);
   int amount = Integer.parseInt(amountTv.getText().toString());
   ConfirmationAction action =
           SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections.confirmationAction()
   action.setAmount(amount)
   Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
}
```

However, when I am trying to follow this, like the guide directs it insists I put pass elements which I want to only set:

[image]

Here is the parts relevant in the nav_graph.xml:

Destination:

[image]

Action:

[image]

I ask, because even only passing them as parameters or passing them as parameters and setting them as well the program claims it didn't receive one of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to pass data(i.e a `Bundle`) using `Navigation Architecture Component`

```
EditText amountTv = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount);
int amount = Integer.parseInt(amountTv.getText().toString());
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("AMOUNT",amount);
findNavController().navigate(R.id.IdOfTheFragemntYouAreTryingToNavigate, bundle, null, null)
```

Comment: I reverted to using a `ViewModel` to access data which I was having problems with yesterday that I manged to get fixed before seeing your answer. I'll accept yours and keep the Q up in case anyone else comes across it.